# Difference between web sockets and WCT netTCP (.NET remoting?)

Tags: php, .net, wcf, sockets, websocket

I have a PHP chatroom that currently uses long polling with JQuery. Someone recommended that I upgrade to using PHP Websockets in order to get my PHP Chatroom to communicate with a project I've been working on for a tutorial in familiarizing myself with dual channel with callbacks in WCF with netTCPBinding. As soon as I looked up chat app-building tutorials, sure enough I started seeing more socket-based programming (which I have not done much of).

Can someone please clarify the difference to me between WCF's netTcpBinding (or a modern version of .NET remoting as I have heard a PluralSight author call it) and using websockets or just sockets in general? And any advice in getting me to connect either a Java chat client or my PHP chatroom connected to my server in my tutorial WCF chat client-server project?

Comment: For .NET projects we simply use SignalR.

Comment: @Lex Li I appreciate that point, but it doesn't answer the theoretical first part of the question. What is the difference between these kinds of programming modes?